# Pre tag giving blank line if no data sent from wicket

Tags: html, wicket

I'm trying to display some data using `pre` tag. Sometimes it won't get any data from the wicket. In that case, it should not show anything on the page. Instead, it is displaying a blank line. Please help on how to prevent the blank line from the page. And I'm sure it is producing because of `pre` tag

```
<div>
  <a wicket:id="Data" class="text-white">Click to View</a>
  <pre wicket:id="Label" class="text-white bg-dark"></pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on Wicket side you can make the component invisible if its model is empty, but maybe you can solve this with a little css:

```
pre:empty {
    display: none;
}
```